# Conjecture: It is not true that $2$ eventually always divides $f(x) = \sum_{d \mid p_{\sqrt{x+1}}\#} (d \mid x^2 - 1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, conjectures, twin-primes

**Lemma.** Let $(d \mid \cdot ) : \Bbb{Z} \to \{0,1\}$ be whether $(1)$ or not $(0)$ $\ d$ divides the input.

There exists no $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall x \geq N$ we have $$f(x) = \sum_{d \mid p_{\pi(\sqrt{x+1})}\#} (d \mid x^2 - 1) = 0 \pmod 2$$

This is a strange conjecture I've come up with that relates to the twin prime problem.

---

**Attempt.**  Suppose the opposite, then we may augment the summation bound of $\pi(\sqrt{x + 1})$ all the way to $\pi(x-2)$, based upon a sieve-of-Eratosthenes argument.  Either way, you'll get $f(x) = 0$.  There are a growing number of primes that occur between $\lfloor\sqrt{x + 1}\rfloor + 1 \dots x - 2$.

If $g(x) =f(x)$ written with the next prime $q = p_{\pi(\sqrt{x + 1}) + 1}$, we have:

$$
0 = f(x) = g(x) = (1 + (q \mid x^2-1))f(x) = f(x) + (q\mid x^2 - 1) f(x) \\
\ = 0 + \sum_{d \mid p_n\#}(qd\mid x^2 - 1), \text{ where } n \equiv \pi(\sqrt{x + 1}).
$$

But we can turn this summation back from whence it came into a product:

$$
0 = g(x) = \prod_{2 \leq p \leq p_n} (1 + (qp \mid x^2 - 1)) \pmod 2
$$

This implies that there exists $p \leq p_n$  such that $(qd \mid x^2-1)$ where $q = p_{\pi(p) + 1}$ is the next prime.

---

Now repeat the procedure, to get:

$$
h(x) = (1 + (r|x^2 -1))g(x) = 0 = g(x) + (r\mid x^2 - 1) g(x) \\
\ = \prod_{2 \leq p \leq  p_n} ( 1 + (rqp\mid x^2 - 1) ) \pmod 2
$$

which means that there exists $p \leq p_n$ such that $rqp = p_n$ where $q, r$ respectively are the next two primes.  Now do this repetitively until you use up all the primes in range $\lfloor \sqrt{x + 1} \rfloor + 1 \dots x -2$.

---

All together, this means:

There exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $x \geq N$ we have that:

$$
p\cdot \prod_{i= \pi(\sqrt{x + 1}) + 1}^{\pi(x - 2)} p_{i}
$$

divides $x^2 - 1$ for some prime $p \leq \sqrt{x + 1}$.  Or in terms of primorial, we have that:

$$
\exists N \in \Bbb{N}:\forall x \geq N, \exists p \leq \sqrt{x + 1}: 
$$

$$
p\frac{(x-2)\#}{\sqrt{x + 1}\#} \mid (x^2 -1)
$$

To someone experienced with numbers, this seems like an absurdity, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it.  The primorial notation is just $(x-2)\#:= p_1 p_2 \cdots p_{\pi(x-2)}$ for example.

Proving (the opposite of) this requires estimating $\pi(x-2) - \pi(\sqrt{x + 1})$ perhaps.

Or can we argue by divisibility that given $x = N$; $x^2 -1$, $(x + 1)^2 -1$ and $(x + 2)^2 - 1$ and so on can't all share the above property.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your conjecture, the summation is indexed by $d$ dividing $p_{\pi(\sqrt{x+1})}\#$. What is $p_{\pi(\sqrt{x+1})}\#$?

Comment: @Servaes  That's simply $p_{n} p_{n-1} \cdots 2$ where $n = \pi(\sqrt{x+1})$.  It's standard primorial notation that every number theorist should know.

Comment: Let $x$ be any real number then $x\#$ can be defined to be the product of all prime numbers $\leq x$.

Comment: I suspected as much, but it was not entirely clear to me from the context. Also, I've managed to complete a PhD in number theory without ever encountering that notation, so you may want to reconsider that claim. In fact I've only seen it online on amateur math fora. Anyway, then my next question is whether you are summing over all integer divisors, just the positive ones, or just those greater than $1$, or something else altogether?

Comment: @Servaes it's summed over all $d \in \Bbb{N}, d \mid \cdot$.  So standard arithmetic function sum-over-divisors way.

Comment: @Servaes I need $x^2-1$ there, it can't be just $x$.   When you change to $x$ the problem becomes different.   The conjecture is that the sum is not eventually always divisible by $2$ or congruent to $0 \pmod 2$ equivalently, as $x$ increases to infinity.  So $\not\exists N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall x \geq N$ we have that the summation is divisible by $2$.

Comment: Please be so kind as to explain this notation before you use it; I see now that you do in fact explain the primorial notation towards the end of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for any positive integer $n$ the map
$$\Bbb{N}_{>0}\ \longrightarrow\ \{0,1\}:\ d\ \longmapsto\ (d\mid n),$$
is multiplicative. It follows that for any positive integer $k$ we have
$$\sum_{d\mid p_k\#}(d\mid n)=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1+(p_i\mid n)\right).$$
This shows that the sum is even if and only if $n$ is divisble by some prime $p\leq p_k$.

This shows that your conjecture is equivalent to the statement that there are infinitely many positive integers $x$ such that $x^2-1$ is not divisible by any prime smaller than $\sqrt{x+1}$. Of course
$$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1),$$
and so both $x+1$ and $x-1$ must then be prime. That is to say, your conjecture is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture.